# Why is break tag showing in span class?

Tags: html, css, tags, line-breaks, break

```
<div class="marker m2">
<span class="hint--top" data-hint="Here is a marker with more text!">
<div class="inner-marker"></div></span></div>
```

My code above is not allowing a line break with in the "data-hint" text. I have tried different variations on break tag but it is still showing within my sentence. A line break does not occur.

Comment: Try to use the html entity of a line break: `&#xa;`

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Line breaks are simply not allowed in `attributes`. Maybe what xphan mentions above, but otherwise they can't be HTML nor use actual line breaks. Maybe `\n` ?

Comment: what css is being applied to this html? you probably have a no-break setting somewhere.

Comment: @j08691 I'm guessing OP wants `word-break` behavior.

Comment: Put a normal break (enter, `\n`, `#10`, you know) in the hint. If necessary, you can replace it with `<br>` in JavaScript when you use it.

Comment: What is everyone talking about? The code provided does not even contain any text that will display - its inside the `data-hint` attribute!

Comment: @somethinghere, you are wrong about line breakes in attributes.

Comment: @Qwerty thanks for the documentation on that. Actually, yes, you can put breaks and spaces everywhere, **but** that will not result in code that is acceptable.

Comment: @Qwertiy Not really. 'Normal breaks' in the context of comments above seems to refer to HTML breaks, is `<br>` tags. And you can't really use those inside attributes. `\n` can be used as *somethingthere* also carefully hints to.

Comment: @GolezTrol, see my answer.

Comment: @Qwertiy Because you _can_ doesn't mean you _should_. It is not good practise to add line breaks in attributes - at most you use unicode or universal signs like `\n`.

Comment: @Qwertiy I already upvoted it even. It's a nice demonstration on how to use these breaks and display them with the help of CSS. Although a bit of textual explanation and/or links to references might make it even better. ;-)

Comment: @somethinghere, can you give link to specification, telling that the break is invalid? [w3c validator](https://validator.w3.org) says that my code is valid except div placement inside of span. Changing span to div makes the code fully valid.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.hint--top::after {
  content: attr(data-hint);
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="marker m2">
<span class="hint--top" data-hint="Here is a marker
with more text!">
<div class="inner-marker"></div></span></div>
```

Comment: You need to explain what you are doing with that.

Comment: @Rob, what explanation youl'd like to see? I think, gigi have to explain what is he doing, anyway, this answer shows solutions for some possible problems.

Comment: SO is not for handing someone a fish but to teach them how to fish. You should explain how and why your markup answers the question.

Comment: @Rob 1. It shows that line break in attribute is possible. 2. It shows what css property have to be used to make linebreakes visible to the user. 3. It shows how to display attribute without js. I don't think that the last point is related to question, but any of the first two does.